# Right click multiple selection in JTable popup menu

Tags: java, jtable, right-click, jpopupmenu

I want to apply my popup menu for multiple rows that I select with the mouse.

When I drag the mouse it selects the rows, but when I right click for popup menu it selects only 1 row. As it shows on the picture: from 1 to 2.

**I want the popup menu to be able to remove mutiple rows at once.**

[image]

If it helps, I am implementing:
MouseAdapter - the method mousePressed.
FocusListener - the method focusGained.
ActionListener - the method actionPerformed .
ListSelectionModel - that implements the valueChanged method.

Also using a JMenuItem , and DefaultTableModel.

Please help.

Comment: “I am implementing: MouseAdapter - the method mousePressed. FocusListener - the method focusGained. ActionListener - the method actionPerformed . ListSelectionModel - that implements the valueChanged method.”  To do what?  Edit your question and include the code for each of those listeners.  My guess is that you are using a MouseListener to display the JPopupMenu;  I recommend avoiding MouseListener and using [setComponentPopupMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu-javax.swing.JPopupMenu-) instead.